# How can I convert a String into a Char list?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a program that removes a specific element from a string, but most of the things I use (like `filter`) only work for `[Char]`. I really just don't want to have to type `"['h','e','l','l','o']"` instead of `"hello"`. I realize that technically a `String` is just a fancy `[Char]`, but how would I unfancify it into a standard `[Char]`. Also if you have another way to write normal words instead of in an array format please tell me.

Comment: `"hello"` and `['h', 'e', 'l','l','o']` are exactly the same.

Comment: A string is not a *fancy* `[Char]`. It is a `[Char]`, period. It is not an array by the way, it is a list. Read about arrays [here](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/arrays.html).

Comment: sry meant to say list not array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was already said, [`String` is simply a *synonym* for `[Char]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#String)

```
type String = [Char]
```

so both can be used interchangeably.

In particular, `"hello" :: [Char]` is exactly the same as `"hello" :: String`, both are just more elegant ways of writing `['h','e','l','l','o']`.

That said, you'll find that not everything that would be a “String” in other languages is a `String` in Haskell. See, the list implementation is actually really inefficient in particular memory-wise – for an ASCII string, most languages take either 8 or 16 bit per character, but with Haskell's `String` type each character is a 64-bit `Char` plus a reference to the next character, for a total 128 bits!

That's why most modern Haskell libraries avoid `String`, except for short things like file names. ([Incidentally](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.html#FilePath),

```
type FilePath = String
```

so that is also interchangeable.)

What these libraries use for general string is typically [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0/docs/Data-Text.html), which is indeed a different type, corresponding more to other languages' implementations (it uses UTF-16 under the hood).

If you want to filter a value of that type, you can either convert it to a listy-`String` with [`unpack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:unpack), or you can simply use the dedicated version of [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:filter) provided by the text library.

In standard Haskell, `Text` values can *not* be defined as string- or list literals, you'd need to explicitly wrap that like `pack ['h','e','l','l','o']`. However they *can* still be defined with a simple string literal, provided that you turn on `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`:

```
ghci> :m +Data.Text
ghci> "hello" :: Text

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "hello" :: Text
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = "hello" :: Text

ghci> :set -XOverloadedStrings 
ghci> "hello" :: Text
"hello"
```

With another extension, this also works for the list syntax:

```
ghci> ['h','e'] :: Text

<interactive>:9:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: ['h', 'e'] :: Text
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = ['h', 'e'] :: Text

ghci> :set -XOverloadedLists 
ghci> ['h','e'] :: Text
"he"
```

Comment: `type FilePath = String` is really quite unfortunate when you're writing code that deals with a bunch of files.

Comment: @dfeuer is it? I can't think of a situation where you could have so many files that it would matter whilst not also running out of inodes. Perhaps with absurdly long file names, but that's not exactly a good idea anyway.

Comment: I don't know how inodes relate. Suppose you have a big directory tree, and you want to walk it and change the owners of all the files in it. For each file, you convert a C string to a `String` and right back to a C string. That's not beautiful. IMO, `FilePath` should be a newtype around `ShortByteString` and there should be facilities to convert to and from `String`. External packages could expose paths as sequences of components and such without having to shove everything through `String`.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, the square brackets mean a list, as they also do in Python. Haskell also uses white space syntax.

You can tell what type a String is in Haskell by using :t in the ghci REPL.

```
:t "String" -- "String" :: [Char]
```

So a string, in double quotes, really is a list of characters.

How about a list of strings?

```
:t ["airplane","boat","car"] -- ["airplane","boat","car"] :: [[Char]]
```

So a list of strings is a list of lists of characters.

As for filtering, if I apply a filter to a string, it behaves exactly as a filter on a list of characters:

```
:m +Data.Char
filter isUpper "String" -- returns "S"
```

Comment: "In Haskell, the square brackets mean a list, as they also do in Python". While this is correct about Haskell, caution should be taken in applying it to Python. While Python indeed calls comma-separated values in square brackets "lists", the name is confusing to a Haskeller because they are in fact implemented as arrays, not linked lists.